# Is Protobuf better at backward compatibility than JSON

Tags: protocol-buffers

I keep reading that protocol buffers are great for backward compatibility due to having numbered fields. But why?

Say V1 model contains firstname and lastname, and V2 adds middlename. If a subscriber has V1 and receives V2 messages both JSON and Protobuf will ignore the middlename nothing breaks.

So when is protobuf better at backward compatibilty than json?

Comment: Either allows you to be backwards compatible, but backwards compatibility always requires some effort to maintain.

Comment: `I keep reading that protocol buffers are great for backward compatibility`... `So when is protobuf better at backward compatibilty than json?` Where does this question come from? What have you read to suggest that this was true?